# Meteor templates with CSS transitions

Tags: meteor

Meteor seems to skip CSS transitions when these are triggered through a template helper. 
Is there a way to work around this?

Example:

```
<template name="example-template">
  <div class="example {{myhelper}}"></div>
</template>
```

Then, "myhelper" would get assigned, through a template helper, a classname that triggers a css transition. But, for some reason, the class is applied but skipping the transition.

I assume this conflicts with Meteor's auto-rendering when the template data sources change, but I don't know how to get around it (I'd like to avoid using jquery for this).

Answer (score 2):

CSS transitions after rendering a new template aren't yet supported by Meteor. The reason is that when rendering the template `example-template` again, the new HTML is just appended to the DOM with the new classname. Since the DOM changes, the transition doesn't happen.

Your best bet is to use the `rendered` event in combination with a `loading` classname:

```
<template name="example-template">
  <div class="example loading"></div>
</template>

Template['example-template'].rendered = function() {
  // remove the loading classname here, and have that trigger a transition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to get easier after new Meteor UI lands (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGQ-ax5cFnk), but until then you can do this with  a preserve directive for your template:

HTML:

```
<template name="example">
  <div id="example-div" class="example {{myhelper}}"></div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.example.preserve(['#example-div']);
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve for more info.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just read the docs carefully: in its simplest form, the `preserve` method should be passed an array of selectors, _each of which should match at most one element_. The good thing about this technique is that your code stays fully reactive.

Comment: `preserve` no longer exists in latest Meteor.