# CSS transitions not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, css, events, meteor, transition

I have tabs where the one selected has bigger height than non selected.

```
<div class="chat-tabs">
<div class="chat-tabs-cont">
    <div id="chat-tab-1" class="chat-tab chat-tab-sel">
        <span class="chat-tab-n">1</span>
        <span class="chat-tab-t">Tab text 1</span>
        <span class="chat-tab-c">11:00</span>
    </div>
    <div id="chat-tab-2" class="chat-tab">
        <span class="chat-tab-n">2</span>
        <span class="chat-tab-t">Tab text 2</span>
        <span class="chat-tab-c">11:30</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is obtained adding/removing the class `chat-tab-sel` who overrides (increases) the standard height of the tab. The `chat-tab` class has a CSS transition: `transition: height .3s ease;`.

But, in Meteor there is no transition, the added/removed class has instant effect.

A similar question is in here [Meteor templates with CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276331/meteor-templates-with-css-transitions) but I tried the preserve method and it made my click events not working, and the loading div not work for this case because the transitions occurs on each tab clicked, not only on first render.

Comment: Try consider creating [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it will help you and other SO-users also in providing you a better solution.

Comment: I think it accomplish the principles mentioned. It has a minimal markup, the css and properties that are involved and no javascript because I still don't have a work-arround in js to solve that (I hope it exists in Meteor). What exactly did you found not well documented?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve. From this point I dont know if there are a way to change a class of a div in Meteor, and get the CSS trasition with it.  Is there an alternative for this? I am not looking for fancy animations, just some CSS3 separated from my javascript should do the job. Any help is appreciatted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after reading several methods and it's really simple, at least for this case.

If you dont want the template to be reactive, dont use Session Vars (that are reactive), use normal variables (static). This way you prevent Meteor to re-render de template and therefore the CSS transition now looks good.

I found this question useful: [Meteor. Prevent template re-rendering or disable reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513046/meteor-prevent-template-re-rendering-or-disable-reactivity)